# pythonic way to find separate integer intervals in dictionary integer mapping

Tags: python

I have a dictionary mapping one integer range onto another, as an example:

```
data = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 6, 8: 6, 9: 7, 10: 8}
```

I want to find all regions where the numeric intervals in the values fail to increment, so my output should be:

```
result = [[6, 8]]
```

For the above input.

I think my answer will involve the grouping itertools recipe described [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples). I tried to do a simple implementation of it for my purposes, but I am unsure how to transform the results into my desired result:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
data = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 6, 8: 6, 9: 7, 10: 8}
for k, pos in groupby(enumerate(data.iteritems()), lambda (i, (a, s)):i - s):
    print map(itemgetter(1), pos)
```

Has the output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]
[(7, 6)]
[(8, 6), (9, 7), (10, 8)]
```

Which properly groups my input data, but does not really give me the interval I want. The challenge I see in parsing this output to the interval I want is that it is giving me an interval for the 'skip region'.

Comment: Does the dictionary always have one entry per index? If so, why not just use a list? If not: How to treat gaps?

Comment: Also, when you say "fail to increment", can we assume that the values remain constant in those regions, or could they also decrease?

Comment: The values will remain constant in those regions, they will not decrease. The keys will always be a complete integer range from `(0, n)` while the values increase monotonically.

These data could be easily stored as a list, just the other tool that calculates these ranges used a dictionary. There is no reason that it can't be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the "non-increasing" values remain constant in those regions and do not decrease either, you can just group entries that have the same value and then pick those groups that have more than one entry. Finally, extract the beginning and the end index.

```
>>> data = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 6, 8: 6, 9: 7, 10: 8}
>>> items = sorted(data.items())
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(items, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> ranges = [grp for grp in (list(grp) for key, grp in groups) if len(grp) > 1]
>>> ranges
[[(6, 6), (7, 6), (8, 6)]]
>>> [(r[0][0], r[-1][0]) for r in ranges]
[(6, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the case that (a) your keys are consecutive integers and (b) you want to find those keys whose values are not greater than the value corresponding to  preceding integer *or* not less than the value corresponding to the successive integer, then:

```
>>> [k for k in sorted(data.keys()) if (k-1 in data and not data[k-1] < data[k]) or (k+1 in data and not data[k] < data[k+1])]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

ranges = defaultdict(list)
data = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 6, 8: 6, 9: 7, 10: 8}
for index, num in data.iteritems():
    ranges[num].append(index)
print [(r[0], r[-1]) for r in ranges.itervalues() if len(r) > 1]
```

One advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require sorting the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that:

```
data = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 6, 8: 6, 9: 7, 10: 8}
sd = sorted(data.items())
result = []
for i in range(1, len(sd)):
    if sd[i][1] == sd[i-1][1]:
        result.append(i)
```

I think `sorted(data.items())` is both clearer and more pythonic that your loop

This gives the result:

```
print result
[7, 8]
```

That might be a good start ?